# Is it appropriate to do assignment to destructured variables?

Tags: javascript, react-native, destructuring

I have declared `state` like this,

```
 this.state = { filtersEnabled: false}
```

and later I `destructured` this object as follows,

```
let { filtersEnabled } = this.state;
```

Now, I want to change the value of `filtersEnabled`,

```
filtersEnabled = true
```

when I do `console.log(this.state.filtersEnabled)`, The answer is => `false`,

But If I change the value as follows

```
 this.state.filtersEnabled = true
```

Now if I do when I do `console.log(this.state.filtersEnabled)`, The answer is => `true`,

What's the problem here,

1.con't we do any assignment to `destructured` variables? or

2.con't we do any assignment to `destructured` state variables?

Comment: `filtersEnabled` is just variable with a boolean value. Any reassignment to it will not affect `state` object. And you are [not supposed](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#using-state-correctly) to update state like this `this.state.filtersEnabled = true`. You need to use `setState`

Comment: Destructuring is completely irrelevant here, you'd have the same result with  `let filtersEnabled = this.state.filtersEnabled;` JavaScript [is a pass by value language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/518000/is-javascript-a-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value-language), you don't get a reference to a primitive when you create a variable for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are changing the value like this:

```
 this.state.filtersEnabled = true
```

You are changing the value of a property. But when you change the value like this:

```
 filtersEnabled = true
```

You basically assign a new value to filtersEnabled. There's no longer a reference to the original value.

Consider this example:

```
let a = 1;
let b = a;
a++;
```

Do you expect `b` to be `2`? No, because `++`, like `+=` and `=` are all operators that create a *new* assignment.

This is also why we need `let` for these cases. `const` would not allow us to make changes.

This, however, does change both:

```
const a = { val: 1 };
const b = a;
a.val++;
```

`b` points to the same object. We never do a re-assignment of `a` (this is also why we can use `const` here), but we do reassign a property *of* `a` (and `b`). So still the same object, but we modified something inside the object.

Answer (score 2):

In React when you want to update `state` you should pass via the `this.setState` method instead of mutating the state directly.

[Do Not Modify State Directly](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#do-not-modify-state-directly)

Performing `destructuring` of the `this.state` will create new variable based on values of different keys get from the Object which is destructured. That will loose any kind of coopling of element with Reference as only object keys can refered to their main reference where ever their are mutate.

```js
let person = {
  "name": "John Doe",
  "age": 40
};

person.name = "Jeanne Doe";

console.log(person);

let { name } = person;
name = "Scott Duck"
console.log(person);
```

As you can see in the example abave after I have destructure the `person` Object the `name` variable isn't tight to the `person` Object any more, We loose the reference to the `person.name` property.

When you access `filtersEnabled` you are no longer accessing the value of component state with the same name but you are accessing the value which that variable hold at a specif time.

To keep tight to the value in the state use `this.setState` to mutate the state and access via `this.state.filtersEnabled` or with the structured value If you know that the value which is holded by created variable from destructuration will be same as value in the `state`, that can be done inside of the `render` as long as we know that the render method will most of time be executed when the state change.

Answer (score 1):

No. By destructing the variable it is converted into a local variable and the state is global so you need to do is `this.state.filtersEnabled = true` to reassign it globally in the state to use everywhere in the class.

By doing `this.state.filtersEnabled = true` It will reassing the value but if you need rerendering the view then you have to do like `this.setState({ filtersEnabled: true});`

Comment: 1. the state is not a global variable. 2. The scope of the variables is irrelevant.

Comment: I have reflected in my answer and updated it